# I received run-time error '1004' Aplication defined or object defined error when i try to put a string in a formula in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, variables, formula

I want to divide all the values from B column to only one value. The problem is: the value is not always on the same position, because the table can have different number of columns. I can get the adress as a String,and only thing I need to do is to insert that value in formula.

I want to make a button which will calculate for all my table that value,and would simplify my work very much

```
Sub CapacityLimit()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim currentColumn As Integer
    Dim currentRow As Integer
    Dim var As Integer
    Dim counter As Integer

     ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Range("A1").Select
     x = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select

     ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Capacity limit/year"

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.ClearContents

     For counter = 1 To x - 1
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC2/" & ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row - 1, ActiveCell.Column + 1).Address & " "
       Next counter
```

this is only a part of my code, the problem is here:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC2/" & ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row - 1, ActiveCell.Column + 1).Address & " "
```

Comment: Address return a xlA1 address by default. FormulaR1C1, as it's name infers, expect R1C1 addresses.

Comment: You can use `... .Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)` but you can probably simply use "=RC2/R-1C1"

Comment: @Vincent shouldn't that be `=RC2/R[-1]C[1]`?

Comment: @chrisneilsen Yes, you're right.

Comment: @vlad Note that your code does not use counter anywhere (the whole loop interact with only one cell), and that it is strongly suggested to avoir using [Select, Selection and other ActiveCell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) if possible